# Detect which template includes the current one in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to detect which template includes another, because I want to have a css class only for one specific template.

Here is how it should work:

```
<template name="includedTempl">    
      <div class="panel panel-default {{#if templateX}}specialCSS{{/if}}" id="{{_id}}">
</template>

Template.includedTempl.helpers({
    templateX: function() {
       if (this.includedBy('templX.html')) {
            return true;
       }
       return false;
    }
});
```

How can I do this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems like an easier solution is to go the other way - pass some context to the child template from the parent template which says "you are special" in the case where it is. For example `{{> includedTemplate special=true}}`. If you think that will work, I can add an answer explaining this is more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it can be challenging for a child template to determine its parent context because it may be nested an arbitrary number of times. Therefore, it's often easier for the parent to provide a context to the child which triggers the desired behavior. Here's an example:

### app.html

```
<body>
  {{> parentTemplate parentContext}}
</body>

<template name="parentTemplate">
  {{> childTemplate specialContext}}
  {{> childTemplate}}
</template>

<template name="childTemplate">
  <div class="{{isSpecialClass}}">
    <p>parent name: {{name}}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

### app.js

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.body.helpers({
    // add some context to the parent do demo how it can be modified
    parentContext: {name: 'dave'}
  });

  Template.parentTemplate.helpers({
    specialContext: function () {
      // make a copy of the parent data context
      var data = _.clone(Template.instance().data || {});
      // modify the context to indicate the child is special
      data.isSpecial = true;
      return data;
    }
  });

  Template.childTemplate.helpers({
    isSpecialClass: function () {
      // grab the context for this child (note it can be undefined)
      var data = Template.instance().data;
      if (data && data.isSpecial)
        // add the 'awesome' class if this child is special
        return 'awesome';
    }
  });
}
```

Here, the parent template creates two child templates. The first child is given the parent context along with `isSpecial`. The template with `isSpecial` will contain a `div` with the `awesome` class. The only tricky part is that both the parent and the child helpers must use [Template.instance](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_instance) to determine their context.

### Recommended Reading

- [A Guide to Meteor Templates and Data Contexts](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-guide-to-meteor-templates-data-contexts/)
- [Scoped Reactivity](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/scoped-reactivity)

Comment: Thanks for that! I think this is the better solution for my case. Have a nice day!!

Comment: I have just one question. I noticed that `this` is now `{ isSpecial: true }` and not the actual object. How can I change this?

Comment: Good question - I modified the example to show how you can extend the parent context. It's a little more complex, but hopefully informative.

Comment: Sorry, but I think it is not working, I created here a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26843042/parentcontext-in-childtemplate-meteor.

Comment: My answer modifies the parent context and not the child context, which I guess it what you wanted. I'll give another solution in the other question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the Template Instance to get the parent name.

```
<template name="parent">
   {{> child }}
</template>

<template name="child">
   <p>
      My father is <b>{{ fatherTemplate abc=23 }}</b>
   </p>
</template>
```

```
Template.child.helpers({
  'fatherTemplate' : function(){
      return UI._templateInstance().view.parentView.name;
  }
});

Template.child.rendered = function(){
    console.log("Father Template name: ", this.view.parentView.name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that! However, I have to use `console.log(UI._templateInstance().view.parentView.parentView.parentView.parentView.name);` to get to my template name. Is there a more 'dynamic' way?

Comment: You can recursively get the parents until you get to the parent you want. The root node/parent is "body", use the name property to check this.