# ParentContext in childTemplate - Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I tried to detect which template includes another, in order to have different css classes for specific template inclusions. I already asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26790701/3475602).

The suggested solution is like this:

app.html:

```
<body>
  {{> parentTemplate parentContext}}
</body>

<template name="parentTemplate">
  {{> childTemplate specialContext}}
  {{> childTemplate}}
</template>

<template name="childTemplate">
  <div class="{{isSpecialClass}}">
    <p>parent name: {{name}}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

app.js

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.body.helpers({
    // add some context to the parent do demo how it can be modified
    parentContext: {name: 'dave'}
  });

  Template.parentTemplate.helpers({
    specialContext: function () {
      // make a copy of the parent data context
      var data = _.clone(Template.instance().data || {});
      // modify the context to indicate the child is special
      data.isSpecial = true;
      return data;
    }
  });

  Template.childTemplate.helpers({
    isSpecialClass: function () {
      // grab the context for this child (note it can be undefined)
      var data = Template.instance().data;
      if (data && data.isSpecial)
        // add the 'awesome' class if this child is special
        return 'awesome';
    }
  });
}
```

Now the problem is that my `childTemplate` has the context of `parentTemplate`. I checked the data of `parentTemplate` and it has the field `isSpecial`, it just has the wrong context. Any idea why this happens? For instance, if I use `{{title}}` in my `childTemplate` I will get the title of the parent context object, but I want the context of the `childTemplate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood the original question. My answer was overly complex because I thought the *parent* context had to be preserved. It's actually a bit easier if you just need to modify the *child* context. Here's a working example:

#### app.html

```
<body>
  {{> parentTemplate}}
</body>

<template name="parentTemplate">
  {{#each children}}
    {{> childTemplate}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="childTemplate">
  <div class="{{isSpecialClass}}">
    <p>name: {{name}}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

#### app.js

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Children = new Mongo.Collection(null);

  Meteor.startup(function () {
    Children.insert({name: 'joe'});
    Children.insert({name: 'bob'});
    Children.insert({name: 'sam'});
  });

  Template.parentTemplate.helpers({
    children: function () {
      // find all of the children and modify the context as needed
      return Children.find().map(function(child, index) {
        // modify the child context based on some aspect of the child or index
        if ((index == 0) || (child.name == 'bob'))
          child.isSpecial = true;

        return child;
      });
    }
  });

  Template.childTemplate.helpers({
    isSpecialClass: function () {
      // add the 'awesome' class if this child is special
      if (this.isSpecial)
        return 'awesome';
    }
  });
}
```

In this version, the parent finds all of the children and modifies each by adding `isSpecial` to the child context **only** if the child is either first in the list or if the child has the name 'bob'. Now, the child only needs to check `this.isSpecial` in its class helper. Please let me know if you have any questions.